# Javascript/jquery popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup

I want to go through the code of advanced popup window just like godaddy's popup (see the picture)

I got following code but it's very simple.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function MM_openBrWindow(theURL,winName,features) { //v2.0
  window.open(theURL,winName,features);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<a href="#" onclick="MM_openBrWindow('popup.html','','scrollbars=yes,width=700,height=700')">click me

</a>
```

For pure educational purposes only, I tried to grab the javascript files and html files for this popup window. But couldn't do it via firebug or any other site grabber. Can someone make or grab the files and post a sample code please which will show a popup exactly as the popup shown in the picture for educational purposes. And the background should be blurred like in the picture.

I know html, but have very little knowledge about javascript/jquery.

[image: Popup window example picture]

P.S : The link to the popup window https://sg.godaddy.com/ and the the clickable text is "* View product limitations and legal policies" and location of the clickable text is bottom of the page.

Regards

Comment: have you considered looking at bootstrap modal?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp

Comment: the thing that popped up is called modal

Comment: yes, it pops up, but the look is not good as picture.

Comment: to get the same look, you will need to modify the CSS

Comment: ok, thanks, and how to make it popup after clicking a text? I mean, instead of clicking the button, if the page has "click here" text and when it click, the popup should appear. onclick event may be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply place the button to text . try it works..!

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal"   data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
```

to

```
 <span type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</span>
```

Comment: Thanks shiva, but this should be `<span type="text" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</span>` to work.